# keep some comments out of the console

Tags: r, rstudio, comments

I'm writing code that will be used by others later and I'd like two kinds of comments to clarify the code.

1. comments that will appear in the console when run so the user sees where in the process R is
2. comments they'll only need when they need to tweak the code

```
#### Recognise, select and clean needed data #### <- I would like this in the console always
source("scripts/3 Recognise rename select and clean needed data.R") # <- my question is not on using source
# this will guarantee you have the column names X Y Z in your data <- I would like to keep this out of the console
```

Is there a way to keep some comments from not appearing in the console?

I searched the internet and the setting in RStudio, but found nothing that addresses this issue specifically.

Comment: This doesn't exist, and it there's also no reason for it to exist in the way the R terminal is *intended* to be used. So the real question is: how you should instead create a process that makes sense in the context of R and  RStudio. In particular, if the code is run via the normal route, users will see *no* comments. And to create diagnostic output, you'd use the `message` function instead.

Comment: Using the message function is a good idea indeed, thanks! So I'll just 'source()' my main script as well and use the 'message' function to only show the need-to-know progress and/or errors in the console.
Just curious, would this be more like the intended use you refer to? I just learned to use R to create and run your own scripts, directly from the script itself.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good approach.